# add .html to custom post type with WPML

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, plugin-wpml

( i open a new question since i found why my slug don't translate in generated links, sorry if it is an error, but sounds logical for me ).

so i use WPML and Custom Posts Type on my wordpress.

i also add .html to my CPT with a code found here on stackexchange.

```
// .html pour les customs posts

function rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    foreach (get_post_types() as $t)
    $new_rules[$t . '/(.+?)\.html$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $t . '&name=$matches[1]';
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules');

function custom_post_permalink ($post_link) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post ) {
        $type = get_post_type($post->ID);
        return home_url() . '/' . $type . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink'); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
```

BUT

with this function, then my generated URLS dont use translated slug, but default language slug and goes to 404.

How can i edit this code to get the correct WPML slug for CPT ?

if i take of this code, it works perfect, but without .html at the end of my URLS.

Thanks a lot for your precious help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleluhia !

it was because $type don't use WPML function

Here is the code that works perfectly with WPML and translated slug :

```
// .html pour les customs posts

function rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    foreach (get_post_types() as $t)
    $new_rules[$t . '/(.+?)\.html$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $t . '&name=$matches[1]';
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules');

function custom_post_permalink ($post_link) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post ) {
        $type = get_post_type($post->ID);
        $slug = apply_filters( 'wpml_get_translated_slug',$type,$type,'');
        return home_url() . '/' . $slug . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html';
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink'); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
```

Comment: just for information, there is a double $type in $slug.
this is because of same parametre for "register_post_type" & "rewrite" option. Change if not the same at your place.